# expo EAS build (iOS) fails in Pod installation step

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods, eas

I am trying to build with the command 'eas build --platform ios' but the build fails At Pod installation step. I also tried to clear the cache but nothing changed.

Here are the log:

````
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `BallNConnect`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNDateTimePicker, RNDeviceInfo, RNFBApp, RNFBFirestore, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, lottie-ios, lottie-react-native, react-native-maps, and react-native-safe-area-context
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
CocoaPods 1.11.3 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.3
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMaps":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-google-maps (from `/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.29.4, which depends on
      Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (= 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
        GoogleMaps
    react-native-google-maps (from `/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.29.4, which depends on
      GoogleMaps (= 3.5.0)
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "nanopb":
  In Podfile:
    EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 7.7.0) was resolved to 7.7.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAnalytics (= 7.7.0) was resolved to 7.7.0, which depends on
          nanopb (~> 2.30907.0)
    RNFBFirestore (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore`) was resolved to 12.9.3, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (= 8.8.0) was resolved to 8.8.0, which depends on
        FirebaseFirestore (~> 8.8.0) was resolved to 8.8.0, which depends on
          nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
[stderr] [!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `6D6F16C9EE89401295D6CEB6` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
Error: Compatible versions of some pods could not be resolved.
You are seeing this error because either:
  - Versions in the Podfile.lock cached by EAS do not match required values in Podspecs of some of the libraries. To fix that add the "cache.key" field (it can be set to any value) in the build profile in eas.json to invalidate the cache.
  - Some of the pods used in your project depend on different versions of the same pod. See logs for more information.```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can only either have ReactNative Firebase (RNFB) or Expo Firebase installed but you cannot install both. Sometimes there is no conflict, but eventually somewhere someplace an issue will arise.

I have spent days on this before, and the only resolution (on the advice of the Expo discord) was to install only one package. This was extremely inconvenient but sometimes expo can lack flexibility IMHO.